# Get access to specific terminal emulator over SSH

Tags: ssh, terminal-emulator

background:
I use a linux box(call it host) everyday. But sometimes, the GUI/mouse/keyboard stop working and it(host) hangs. I was not able to do anything but restart it(host). So, now i always a ssh server running on it(host) so that I can connect to it and turn off things safely. I do this by using VNC client on my laptop(call it REMOTE). It replicates the whole screen from the host, so even if my mouse/keyboard on the host don't work, i could close things with REMOTE. But VNC is expensive on network usage and slow. I want to replace it with normal ssh connection.

problem redefined: 
So, if I start a simple program to print "hello world" endlessly on terminal on the "host". How can i see the same terminal(with hello world printing) on "REMOTE" over SSH. Not just see, control this program say stop it, kill it etc.